# Overcoming code duplication with Graphql-js schemas

Tags: mongodb, graphql, graphql-js

I'm learning GraphQL with GraphQL-Js & Mongo.

I'm finding that there are a lot of code duplication with GraphQL the pattern.

My GraphQL Input Object looks like this:

```
const PricingInputType = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: 'PricingInput',
  fields: () => ({
    expires: { type: GraphQLInt },
    private: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
    monthly: { type: GraphQLInt },
    scanEnvelope: { type: GraphQLInt },
    initalScan: { type: GraphQLInt },
    perPage: { type: GraphQLInt },
    forwardMail: { type: GraphQLInt },
    forwardParcel: { type: GraphQLInt },
    shred: { type: GraphQLInt },
    perMonthPerGram: { type: GraphQLInt },
    freeStorePerGram: { type: GraphQLInt },
    setup: { type: GraphQLInt },
    idFree: { type: GraphQLInt }
  })
});

const PlanInputType = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: 'PlanInput',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLString },
    planName: { type: GraphQLString },
    pricing: { type: PricingInputType }
  })
});

const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Mutation',
  fields: {
      addPlan: {
          type: PlanType,
          args: {
            Plan: { type: PlanInputType }
          },
          resolve(parent, args){
            //TO DO. UPSERT TO MONGO
              return true;
          }
      }
    }
});
```

where my query object looks like:

```
const PricingType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Pricing",
  fields: () => ({
    expires: { type: GraphQLInt },
    private: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
    monthly: { type: GraphQLInt },
    scanEnvelope: { type: GraphQLInt },
    initalScan: { type: GraphQLInt },
    perPage: { type: GraphQLInt },
    forwardMail: { type: GraphQLInt },
    forwardParcel: { type: GraphQLInt },
    shred: { type: GraphQLInt },
    perMonthPerGram: { type: GraphQLInt },
    freeStorePerGram: { type: GraphQLInt },
    setup: { type: GraphQLInt },
    idFree: { type: GraphQLInt }
  })
});

const PlanType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Plan",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLString },
    planName: { type: GraphQLString },
    pricing: { type: PricingType }
  })
});

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "RootQueryType",
  fields: {
    plans: {
      type: new GraphQLList(PlanType),
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return Plans.find({});
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Now my Mongo Schema looks like this:

```
var plansSchema = new Schema({
  planName:  {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Plan name is required"]
  },
  pricing: {
    monthly: Number,
    scanEnvelope: Number,
    initalScan: Number,
    perPage: Number,
    forwardMail: Number,
    forwardParcel: Number,
    shred: Number,
    perMonthPerGram: Number,
    freeStorePerGram: Number,
    setup: Number,
    idFree: Number
  },
  expires: Number,
  private: Boolean,
  deleted: Boolean,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

module.exports =  mongoose.model('plans', plansSchema);
```

As you can see I'm duplicating code in 3 places. If I decide to charge quarterly instead of Monthly, I need to change the Monthly property in 3 places!?

Is there a better pattern? or is this just the way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48790703/9278956) to a similar question. It uses a [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-to-mongodb) that relies on the GraphQL "query object" to generate everything else and therefore forgoes mongoose to use straight MongoDB.